# Does electromagnetic wave violates conservation of energy when passing between two dielectric mediums at oblique angles, is there a derivation?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, poynting-vector

how can we prove that poynting theorem works for an Electromagnetic waves which incident at  an oblique angles between two dielectric medium?

Answer (score 0):

Poyntings theorem is the proof. In integral form it says in this case that the surface integral of Poyntings vector over a surface spanning the interface is zero, if we choose a pillbox shape with vanishingly small volume, and zero current in either medium.
You can of course set out to check it, but if you can't then you must have made a mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of energy at the interface requires continuity of the normal component of Poynting's vector
$$\textbf S_1\cdot\textbf n=\textbf S_2\cdot\textbf n$$
where $\textbf n$ is the unit normal to the interface. This follows from the boundary conditions we impose at the interface: continuity of the parallel components of $\textbf E$ and $\textbf H$. We decompose the fields into components normal and parallel to the interface: $\textbf E=(\textbf E\cdot\textbf n\,\textbf n)+(\textbf E-\textbf E\cdot\textbf n\,\textbf n)$ where the second term is the parallel component, and similarly for $\textbf H$. The normal component of the Poynting vector is then
$$\textbf S\cdot\textbf n=\textbf E\times\textbf H\cdot\textbf n.$$ The normal components give zero contribution in this triple scalar product because of the repeated $\textbf n$ and so only the continuous parallel components contribute. Hence the normal component of $\textbf S$ is continuous.

My first answer is correct, but I think this answer gives more insight into how the conservation works in terms of fields. The continuity of the parallel components gives us the conditions to be satisfied at the interface, and hence the reflection and transmssion coefficients etc. Thus all of these must respect conservation of energy.